# Why is my 1 line command in cmd not working?

Tags: shell, gcc, cmd, terminal, directory

I have this command to automatically create a folder `bin` if it doesn't exist already:

```
if not exist bin mkdir bin
```

I have another command to compile a C file and put it in the `bin` folder:

```
gcc hello_world.c -o bin/hello_world.exe
```

When I join the commands together like this:

```
if not exist bin mkdir bin && gcc hello_world.c -o bin/hello_world.exe
```

If the `bin` folder doesn't exist already, it works fine. But when the bin folder already exists, the
second command doesn't run.

Why and how did this happen?

Edit: I have tried out using only 1 `&` but it's stillt he same result.

Comment: No need for an `if`. `mkdir` won't do anything if the folder already exists (except setting an errorlevel). Use `&` ("and then do") instead of `&&`("if that was successful then do"). `Mkdir` "fails" to create the folder if it already exists. `mkdir bin & gcc hello_world.c -o bin/hello_world.exe` should work fine for you.

Comment: Do you want `gcc` to be executed independent on the result of `if exist`? if so, you need to place parentheses like this: `(if not exist bin mkdir bin) & gcc hello_world.c -o bin/hello_world.exe`…

Comment: The __IF__ condition is not needed at all on using `mkdir bin 2>nul & gcc.exe hello_world.c -o bin/hello_world.exe`. The error message output by `mkdir` on directory `bin` already existing is suppressed by redirecting it from handle __STDERR__ to device __NUL__. Next `gcc.exe` is executed independent on success or failure creating the subdirectory `bin`. If you want to use an __IF__ condition, I recommend to use `mkdir bin 2>nul & if exist bin gcc.exe hello_world.c -o bin/hello_world.exe` which first creates the directory and next checks if the directory exists in which case `gcc.exe` is run.

Answer (score 0):

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>(if not exist bin mkdir bin) & echo %errorlevel%
1

C:\WINDOWS\system32>(if not exist bin mkdir bin) & echo %errorlevel%
0
```

`&&` means run the next command only if `%errorlevel%` is 0. Change to `&`.

See https://winsourcecode.blogspot.com/2019/12/command-prompt-cheat-sheet.html

Comment: I'm afraid that your solution didn't solve my problem. It's still the same result.

Comment: You're right about `&&` but you code is wrong as it lacks [delayed expansion](https://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html) for `ErrorLevel`…